# Programmatically Process all Sitecore items with Workflow

Tags: c#, workflow, sitecore, sitecore6, sitecore7

I have situation where I have a lot items in the `Workbox` that I need to clear out.

I need to process these items so that they can be assigned a workflow state (without triggering workflow actions) according to this rule:

If the item has a state of draft or waiting for approval and there is a published version higher than the current version then set the workflow state to be `x` worflowstate.

I haven't done much experimenting with workflow, so does anybody have any code samples or thoughts of how I could achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a blog post about [Changing workflow state of Sitecore items programmatically](http://www.cognifide.com/blogs/sitecore/changing-workflow-state-of-sitecore-items-programmatically/) .

First you need to find all items in chosen workflow states:

```cs
IWorkflow[] workflows = Sitecore.Context.Database.WorkflowProvider.GetWorkflows();

IWorkflow chosenWorkflow = workflows[..]; // choose your worfklow

WorkflowState[] workflowStates = chosenWorkflow.GetStates();

foreach (WorkflowState state in workflowStates)
{
    if (!state.FinalState)
    {
        DataUri[] itemDataUris = chosenWorkflow.GetItems(state.StateID);
        foreach (DataUri uri in itemDataUris)
        {
            Item item = Sitecore.Context.Database.GetItem(uri);
            /* check other conditions - newer version exists etc */
            ChangeWorkflowState(item, newWorkflowStateId);
        }
    }
}
```

The simplest code for changing workflow state of **Sitecore** item without executing any actions related to the new workflow state is:

```cs
public static WorkflowResult ChangeWorkflowState(Item item, ID workflowStateId)
{
    using (new EditContext(item))
    {
        item[FieldIDs.WorkflowState] = workflowStateId.ToString();
    }

    return new WorkflowResult(true, "OK", workflowStateId);
}

public static WorkflowResult ChangeWorkflowState(Item item, string workflowStateName)
{
    IWorkflow workflow = item.Database.WorkflowProvider.GetWorkflow(item);

    if (workflow == null)
    {
        return new WorkflowResult(false, "No workflow assigned to item");
    }

    WorkflowState newState = workflow.GetStates()
        .FirstOrDefault(state => state.DisplayName == workflowStateName);

    if (newState == null)
    {
        return new WorkflowResult(false, "Cannot find workflow state " + workflowStateName);
    }

    return ChangeWorkflowState(item, ID.Parse(newState.StateID));
}
```

Comment: Hey Marek Musielak. i am also working on workflow related task.can i have your skype id to get help